# psql connects, but pgadmin3 fails

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I'm connecting to a remote database using psql which works fine.

```
psql "host=dbhost user=dbuser pass=dbpass"
```

But supplying the same settings to pgadmin3 fails with "access to database denied" with a "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" message. How is psql working when pgadmin3 fails?

I do not have a .psqlrc file.

Comment: The database name is suspiciously absent. I suspect you are accessing different databases.

Comment: That put me on the right path. I didn't consider psql might connect to a different default. When I specified the database name in pgadmin it connected fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this turned out to be that psql and pgadmin have different default databases. Changing the default in pgadmin fixed the issue. Thanks to Laurenz Albe for helping answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You know of course that PGAdmin defaults to localhost. If you wish to use it on a remote database you need to record a new remote server in PGAdmin, particularly specifying the dbhost in the connection tab.